# How to apply obfuscator-loader to ts files with ts-loader

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I want to compile my typescript into javascript *and then* run another loader to obfuscate it (take the bundle.js and obfuscate it into another file).

Seems like it should be easy, but when I tried different options, it's just not happnin'. I tried having an entry point for bundle.js, but that doesn't seem to work either. What's the best way to do this?

```
module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: {
    bundle: "./main.ts",
},
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  module:{
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.tsx?$/,
            include: [ path.resolve(__dirname, ".") ],
            use: {
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                loader: 'obfuscator-loader'
            },
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the necessary loaders on top of the list:

```
module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: {
    bundle: "./main.ts",
},
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  module:{
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.tsx?$/,
            include: [ path.resolve(__dirname, ".") ],
            use: [
                 'obfuscator-loader',
                 'ts-loader',
            ],
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }
```

Execution order is always from bottom to top. obfuscator -> ts-loader-> other-random-loader

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't quite do it for an interesting reason. It appears from this error that the second webpack module is operating before the ts has been fully compiled to js and (I guess) that triggers an error. 

        ERROR in ./main.ts
        Module build failed (from ./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js):
        TypeError: this.cacheable is not a function

It seems like the simplest solution is to use the ts compiler in package.json instead of the webpack loader. That way, everything WebPack sees will be fully-compiled javascript.

Comment: You are trying to run obfuscator After ts-loader? Which loaders do you want to run, and in which orders? Because your question is not that clear tbh

Comment: OK. I want to do the following tasks: 1) compile all .ts files into javascript 2) pack .js files (with WebPack). -- into bundle.js 3) run obfuscator on the compiled, packed javascript file.

Comment: @SDAFO that is the order you have to put your loaders. It is going to compile/transpile typescript and run the obfuscator for each typescript file transpiled.

Comment: \

When I modify my code to run ts-loader and then obfuscator, it triggers an error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js): TypeError: this.cacheable is not a function
    at Object.loader

use: [
                'ts-loader',
                 'obfuscator-loader'
            ],

Comment: By doing that, obfuscator is going to run first, then ts-loader... your compilation will have errors